# BlueJ - tools.jar not found

Tags: java, bluej

I installed BlueJ today and I got the program able to load up however when I try to create/open a project the application doesn't do anything. Upon executing the command in terminal I found the error:

```
class Boot: tools.jar not found. Potential problem for execution. (Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre)
```

I am not sure how to edit the Java home varaible. I have changed the `/etc/environment` file to contain:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk"
export JAVA_HOME
```

However that doesn't affect anything (I still get the same error message with the same path)

Manjaro 17.1.2

Linux 4.14.14-1-MANJARO

BlueJ 4.1.2-1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. I run Arch Linux, which from my understanding Manjaro is pretty similar?

The problem I had was when I installed bluej I think I selected the Java 7 option when it gave me a choice between Java 7, 8, and 9.

I ran `archlinux-java status` to check which version I had selected on my system, and this was the result:

`Available Java environments:
  java-8-openjdk/jre (default)`

So all I had to do was totally remove bluej (`pacman -Rns bluej`), and then reinstall and ensure I selected the `2) jdk8-openjdk` option when given the choice. My bluej installation now creates and opens projects as expected.

Hopefully some of that information is useful, I must admit, I am pretty new to Linux, so don't really know what I am talking about. Just sharing my experience.

EDIT: I had the same problem on my other arch machine, and the issue was simply that I had the java-8-jde/jdk installed but for some reason that meant that bluej was looking in the jre for tools.jar I guess? So I installed java-8-openjdk and that solved my problem, bluej now works on this computer as well. I am yet unsure as to whether that will cause other Java issues on the system though, but I feel like it won't?